# Complete details for each REST api endpoint on Firebase Performance Console

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit2, firebase-performance

I have integrated the firebase performance monitoring in my app and I am also trying to fetch the details for each http request and using default implementation to check that.

**HttpClient :** Retrofit

But after a day or two I can see some data under the Network section but that too unacategorized and based on host. 
Is it possible to get complete details for each endpoint ?

Comment: Everything you see in the dashboard is all the information you can access.  There's nothing else available.

Comment: Okay @DougStevenson . So there is no direct process but I think I can use Custom Traces to achieve the same. Is it right ?

Comment: You can use a custom trace for whatever you want to measure.

Comment: Cloud Functions do not (yet) expose Firebase Performance, therefore it is not possible to create an API, which one could use to obtain the metrics.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. Trace works as required. If needed this question can be closed.